# Orchard CMS: How to apply template for part created in dashboard?

Tags: orchardcms

I have created a content type with one content part in the dashboard, I want to create a template for this content part.

But I see shapes only for the fields of this part, not for part itself.
Is it possible to create templates for dashboard created parts?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. There is no difference between shapes from dynamic type and shapes from types defined from code.

However, if you want a shape to override, you need a shape in the first place. If the part got built from the admin dashboard, it won't emit a shape for itself, only shapes for its fields. You should probably write a proper part, using code.

Comment: But how to get dynamic part shape in output? 
I have following shape tree in ShapeTrace http://rmdi.ru/upload/xxx1.jpg

Comment: Does it need some changes in Placement.info?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking now. Shape tracing is clearly showing you the shapes, and it even has buttons to create alternates directly from the first tab.

Comment: In my case I have created ItemImagePart in dashboard. This part contains two MediaPicker fields. Shape tracer shows me shapes for fields but not for part. I want to apply template for part, but I don't understand where is shape for ItemImagePart.

Comment: I see. If you want a shape to override, you need a shape in the first place. If the part got built from the admin dashboard, it won't emit a shape for itself, only shapes for its fields. You should probably write a proper part, using code.